# unable to install magento2 sample data php bin/magento sampledata:deploy

Tags: magento2, php, database, error, cli

php bin/magento sampledata:deploy

> [Exception]   Warning:
>   file_get_contents(G:/ma_oxelar/app/code/Plazathemes/Layout/compose
>   r.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   G:\ma_oxelar\v   endor\magento\module-sample-data\Model\Dependency.php
>   on line 109

sampledata:deploy

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the magento file in bin directory with the new one and run the following command on magento file if your host is linux:

**sudo chmod u+x bin/magento**
[image]

> Note: Before running bash command make sure your current working
>   directory must be Magento 2.x root.